# How do I get the 12.04 login screen to turn off screen after timeout?

Tags: 12.04, login, screensaver

On 12.04, the login screen doesn't timeout or go to screensaver after a set time. I have a number of machines in a testbed that spend a lot of time waiting for logins and I'm afraid the monitors will get damaged. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has now gone in Precise after an upgrade (I admit, I experienced that problem too). I suggest you to upgrade your machines. May be that was a bug

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Your monitors won't be damaged from lack of screensaver :D

1. To set timed screen turn off with lock enter System Settings -> Brightness and Lock.
2. Set "Turn screen off when inactive for:"
3. Set "Lock" to ON
4. Set "Lock screen after:" to "Screen turns off"